# Tips for Golfing in Vitsy

Tags: code-golf, tips

While there are only a few users of the [Vitsy programming language](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) right now, I wish to create a place for tips for golfing in Vitsy.

What general tips do you have for golfing in [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy)? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) (e.g. "remove NOPs" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

For reference, the online interpreter is [here](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net), the esolang page is [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Vitsy), and you can receive answer-per-answer help [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35039/ppcg-code-snippet-chat-bot).

Answer (score 2):

## Do not doubt the power of `m`

Background: `Fm` calls the a specified line index in the current Vitsy class. (`F` is the line index you seek).

The `m` command (method) has saved me [literally hundreds of bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74216/44713) in the past. Any algorithm that uses repeated steps, or a common character sequence (such as `D1M-` (floor algorithm)).

This is extremely helpful in repetitive kolmogorov complexity challenges.

Instead of:

```
WD1M-(something else here)WD1M-(something different)WD1M-l\[NaO]
```

Use:

```
1m(something else here)1m(something different)1ml\[NaO]
WD1M-
```

(floor(prompt))

Also, you can return from method statements with `;`, allowing for looping until condition(s) (over the general `[  ]` syntax, which isn't as powerful):

```
1mN
<;)
```

(loops through code until finding non-zero, popping it from the stack and returning to first line)

Comment: Since many people here don't know vitsy, perhaps briefly explain what `m` does?

Comment: @Cyoce Yes, sorry. c: Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

## Remember that `\[]` *always runs at least once*

Even if the top item of the stack is zero or less, `\[]` always runs. Think of it more as a `do{}for();` loop. This has caught me off more than once, but it is important.

Answer (score 1):

## Filling Zeroes on an Empty Stack

Normally, to fill up the stack with a number, you would do something like this:

```
a\a
```

This fills up the stack with 10 10s, by pushing 10 10 times. However, if you wanted to push 10 0s, you'd do this:

```
a\0
```

After a recent update, however, the stack will attempt to fix for IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions by pushing 0s to a possibly empty stack, meaning that, if on an empty stack, you can do:

```
a%
```

Since `%` calls `multistack`, it tries to access every member between the top item (which is nothing after it pops `10`) and the index you specify. Therefore, you get a stack with 10 0s when this is called. You can use this trick up to approximately 11380, although, annoyingly, it doesn't always go to a specific point...

```
UNKNOWN:Desktop addisonc17$ vitsy --code "2d^2b^+2a^+26^+25^+24^+5+%lNaO"
java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown in [command line] at command #0,25: %
UNKNOWN:Desktop addisonc17$ vitsy --code "2d^2b^+2a^+26^+25^+24^+5+%lNaO"
11381
```

Past that, you'll have to use the normal duplication method.